# Converse of an equation of Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We know that  if, $a\equiv b \pmod n$ then $$a^n\equiv b^n \pmod n$$ Is the converse true for odd $n$? The converse isn't true for even because $3^4 \equiv 1^4 \pmod 4$ but $3 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ isn't true. If the converse is true for odd n then give me a proof of this. If the converse isn't true for all odd $n$ then what is the condition of $(a,b,n)$ so that the converse is true.

Comment: the converse is not true for all composite odd $n$; e.g., $1^9\equiv4^9\bmod9$

Answer (score 1):

It's true for prime $n$ because $a^n\equiv a\pmod n$ for prime $n$ by Fermat's little theorem.

This is also true for [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), which are composite.